# mp3 id3 tag comparison

Tags: windows, mp3, id3

I have a large music collection where every other mp3 file has id3 v2.1, v2.2 and v2.3 tags.
I don't know why but some of these files have valuable info. stored in the v2.2 tags but not in the v2.3.

I use mp3tag to manage, edit and format all my mp3s, but the tool doesn't offer any way to compare data stored in different version of id3.

Is there any tool capable of doing this on Windows?

Comment: is auto-retagging an option? Just leave the older tags as they are and auto-retag to v2.3?

Comment: No, it is not, I want to merge those tags manually

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but
[MP3I](https://archive.org/details/mp-3-i)
Will show you all the meta data inside and can be piped to an output file for text based comparison.

Does require Java 8+ though.